# Share links with captions, names, pictures, and descriptions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I'm trying to use the `/links` methods from [the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and can't seem to get it to use the names, captions, pictures, or descriptions I'm passing. Are these arguments deprecated or something?

Here's my sample call:

```
curl -F 'access_token=<my_token>' \
     -F 'link=http://spectate.com' \
     -F 'message=Spct8?' \
     -F 'picture=http://spectate.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/spec_rgb.png' \
     -F 'name=Spectate' \
     -F 'caption=a' \
     -F 'description=my desc' 
     https://graph.facebook.com/<wall_id>/links
```

The [link and message appear fine](http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=298245196866489&id=141130022632683) but it doesn't use the picture, caption, name or description.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566968/graph-api-link-name-caption-description-picture-not-showing-up) and [resolved as a Facebook API bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194522957295380). The workaround is to post to `/feed` as noted in the bug. The caveat is that the link is unshareable.