# How to post message to a Facebook fanpage? (not the user feed)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to publish from a site to Facebook wall. My intention is to create something similar to BandPage that has great **wall** functionality. Example: *facebook.com/junkiepunksdj?sk=app_178091127385*

I would like to share resources that are available to me so you could point me in a right direction. **Is this a right approach?**

- GREAT TUTORIAL: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/
- very similar question posted here: [How do you post to the wall on a facebook page (not profile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile)
- I can emulate Facebook wall using this plugin: *neosmart.de/blog/jquery-plugin-facebook-wall*
- I can create simple dialog: *developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/* Just by redirecting to sample URL: *on.fb.me/shortened-link-to-facebook-dialog*
- I can publish to my wall using customized features using FB JS: *stefanow.net/stuff/twistedmusic/test-publish.php (my sample site)*

That's all I know. I going in circles getting more are more complicated errors. All I really want to do is to **publish message to a fanpage**. I would be really glad for piece of working code.

PS. Some of the links are italic couse I cannot post more than two :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two ways to post to a fanpage: [how does one post a thumbnail picture to a Facebook /links object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327996/how-does-one-post-a-thumbnail-picture-to-a-facebook-links-object)

the /links method has the problems noted.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/ - "A link shared on a user's wall." - I need to post to a **PAGE**...

Comment: it does post to a page, as indicated.